# Markdown shortcut for base link

Tags: markdown

I can use reference links to shorten the code I have to write. Suppose the path to file1 is /path/to/folder/file1. Then I can put

```
[file1][pathtofile1]


[pathtofile1]: /path/to/folder/file1
```

My question is what if I had a bunch of files (file1, file2, file3, etc), and I wanted to similarly shorten my code. Can I do something like

```
[filek][pathtofile/filek]

[pathtofile]: /path/to/folder
```

where k = 1,2,3, etc.

Comment: You can do this with Liquid, ERB, or similar templating engine. No way it will work with base markdown.

Comment: Yeah. I found out i could do it with liquid. For some reason I thought it would be possible in markdown. Can I do it with just html?

Comment: You need something that can do a `for` loop, HTML will not do that

Comment: ok. thanks. I guess html is really hard to code in.